# Django Template DIRS TemplateDoesNotExist: Why are some templates being skipped (Skipped)?

Tags: python, django, django-scheduler

I'm trying out the sample project for [django-scheduler](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler-sample). When I try to load 127.0.0.1 it throws `TemplateDoesNotExist` for `base.html`. Debug = True says:

```
Django tried loading these templates, in this order:

Using engine django:

django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: D:\Code\django-calendar-sample\django-scheduler-sample\project_sample\templates\base.html (Skipped)
django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader: D:\Code\django-calendar-sample\django-scheduler-sample\project_sample\templates\base.html (Skipped)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\templates\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\templates\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\debug_toolbar\templates\base.html (Source does not exist)
django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader: D:\Code\django-calendar-sample\django-scheduler-sample\project_sample\templates\base.html (Skipped)
```

Note the very end of the first two lines (where base.html actually exists) it shows (Skipped). Why were they skipped?

Comment: You have a recursion error. `django-scheduler-sample\project_sample\templates\base.html` itself attempts to extend `base.html` which doesn't make sense unless you provide a separate`base.html` that it can extend from.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @solarissmoke you're correct;

In `base.html`:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load i18n %}
{% block extra_head %}
{{ block.super }}
{% endblock %}

{% block rtab_id %}id="schedule_tab"{% endblock %}

{% block subnav %}
<ul>
    {% if user.is_authenticated %}
        <li><a href="">{% trans "Create a Calendar" %}</a></li>
        <li><a href="">{% trans "Your Calendars" %}</a></li>
    {% endif %}

        <li><a href="">{% trans "All Calendars" %}</a></li>
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```